# How to add new sheets to existing excel workbook using apache POI and PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a new sheet in an existing excel workbook using apache POI using primefaces and java but have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone please tell me how it is done?
I am able to do it for single sheet

The below code i have written for creating multiple sheets in one xls file, where i given the condition that it has no of rows greater than 65535 create new sheet and iterate it, but it is showing error

WARNING: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)

My code is

```
 public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {
 HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
        font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setWrapText(false);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_GENERAL);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        System.out.println("Row number:"+sheet.getLastRowNum());
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            System.out.println("Row number:"+sheet.getLastRowNum());
             //sheet.rowIterator().next().getRowNum();
             if(sheet.getLastRowNum() >= 65535) 
             {
                 String sheetName = "";
                 for(int i=0;i<searchResults.size();i++)
                 {
                     sheetName = "Document-" + i; 
                     HSSFSheet mySheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName); 
                     HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                     Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
                     while (iterator.hasNext()) 
                     {
                         HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) iterator.next();
                         hssfCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
  }
```

and in my xhtml

```
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/excel.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="nmeadata"
                    postProcessor="#{decodeNMEAMessageAction.postProcessNmeaXLS}"
                    fileName="decoded_all_nmeadata" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/excel.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="nmeadata"
                    postProcessor="#{decodeNMEAMessageAction.postProcessNmeaXLS}"
                    fileName="decoded_page_nmeadata" pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>
```

[image: Datatable which is imported to excel sheet]

Is it possible to export data to multiple sheets using primefaces.
Other wise please tell me how it can be done using servlets.

Comment: not related to primefaces is it?

Comment: @user2310289 it is related to primefaces only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);`

`HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();`

basically what you want is to createSheet -> createRow -> createCell -> serCellValue

The Javadocs are excellent

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/package-summary.html

Comment: it is creating a sheet, but not writing into it

Comment: and again - `sheet.createRow ()` - you need to create new objects

Comment: Actually i want to write messages to sheet based on the type like IIMWV,AVIDO,etc.Can you please tell me how it is done.